# Swagger "required" vs "nullable" for codegen

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I noticed while generating an API client using the `typescript-fetch` generator that the generated interfaces designate all properties as nullable, even when not designated as nullable in the swagger/open API definition. Furthermore, the only time they were made non-nullable is when the property was annotated with `required = true`.

I haven't found a clear distinction between "required" and "nullable" as it relates to how it should affect codegen, but intuitively, "required" seems like it should have clients enforce that a value be present when creating a request, while having `nullable = false` (which is the default) should generate a property on the response object that isn't nullable.

I'm looking for a clear distinction between the two, in order to identify if there is an issue with code-gen with respect to designating fields nullable or not.